# Express Validator разделить код на routes и controllers

Tags: node.js, express-validator

Как правильно разделить код (пример приведен ниже) на две части 
1) routes.js -> app.post('user', user.create)
2) controllers.js -> create = (req, res) => {...}

Код взят из документации по ссылке https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

```
// ...rest of the initial code omitted for simplicity.
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/user', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller.js

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

class Controller {
   static async createUser(req){
     const errors = validationResult(req);
     if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        throw { error: {errors:errors.array()}, status:422 };
     }

     const { username, password } = req.body;
     const user = await User.create({ username, password });
     return user;
   }
}

module.exports = Controller
```

routes.js

```
const Controller = require('./controller.js');
const { check } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/user', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], async (req, res)=>{
   try{ 
       const user = await Controller.createUser(req);
       res.json(user);
   } catch (err){
       const {status, error} = err;
       res.status(status).json(error);
   }
})
```